# PostgreSQL. Извлечение пары ключ-значение из массива в JSON

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Нужно вытащить все пары значений id:name для каждого oid из массива questionOptions в JSON.

Есть таблица в PostgreSQL Mytable:
тип поля data: jsonb

| oid | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"id":1,"name":"Тестовый опрос","questionSections":[{"id":11,"name":"Тестовая группа","questions":[{"id":111,"name":" Тест","optionSections":[{"id":1111,"name":"Тест2","questionOptions":[{"id":1112,"value":"Тестовое"}]}]}]}]} |

Результат:

| oid | id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1111 | Тест2 |
| 1 | 1112 | Тестовое |

В цейтноте, было бы время сам бы решил задачу, но к сожалению надо уже сдавать. JSON только осваиваю, не всё понятно. Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
     oid
    ,que.qval ->> 'id' AS qid1
    ,que.qval ->> 'name' AS name
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            m.id AS oid
            , qs.questionsections ->> 'id' AS id
            , jsonb_array_elements_text(jsonb_array_elements_text(jsonb_array_elements_text(jsonb_array_elements_text(m.poll_questions -> 'questionSections'::TEXT)::jsonb -> 'questions'::TEXT)::jsonb -> 'optionSections'::TEXT)::jsonb -> 'questionOptions'::TEXT)::json AS qval
        FROM
            mytable m
            , LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(m.poll_questions -> 'questionSections'::TEXT) qs(questionsections)
    );
```

Comment: Спасибо за правку, отвлекся на другую задачу.